# MS SQL Query changed plan and became incredibly slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

We have a query that has been running for over 3 year without any problems.

The query is a standard one from our ERP system (Microsoft Dynamics AX) and it goes like this:

```
SELECT SUM(B.COSTAMOUNTPOSTED),SUM(B.QTY) FROM INVENTTRANSPOSTING A,INVENTTRANS B 
WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=N'01') AND (((A.ITEMID=@P1) AND (A.INVENTTRANSPOSTINGTYPE=@P2)) AND (A.TRANSDATE>@P3))) 
AND ((B.DATAAREAID=N'01') AND ((((B.VOUCHER=A.VOUCHER) AND (B.DATEFINANCIAL=A.TRANSDATE)) 
AND (B.INVENTTRANSID=A.INVENTTRANSID)) AND (B.PACKINGSLIPRETURNED=@P4))) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM INVENTDIM C WHERE ((C.DATAAREAID=N'01') AND ((((((((((C.INVENTDIMID=B.INVENTDIMID) AND (C.CONFIGID=@P5)) AND (C.INVENTSIZEID=@P6)) AND (C.INVENTCOLORID=@P7)) AND (C.INVENTSITEID=@P8)) AND (C.INVENTLOCATIONID=@P9)) AND (C.INVENTBATCHID=@P10)) AND (C.WMSLOCATIONID=@P11)) AND (C.WMSPALLETID=@P12)) AND (C.INVENTSERIALID=@P13)))
```

or in a more readable form:

```
select TableId from inventTransPosting           
        where inventTransPosting.ItemId                 == itemId                            &&
              inventTransPosting.InventTransPostingType == InventTransPostingType::Financial &&
              inventTransPosting.TransDate              >  perDate
    join sum(CostAmountPosted),sum(Qty) from inventTrans            
        where inventTrans.Voucher                       == inventTransPosting.Voucher        &&
              inventTrans.DateFinancial                 == inventTransPosting.TransDate      &&
              inventTrans.InventTransId                 == inventTransPosting.InventTransId  &&
              inventTrans.PackingSlipReturned           == NoYes::No
    exists join inventDim   
        where inventDim.inventDimId == inventTrans.inventDimId &&
              inventDim.configId    == configId &&
              inventDim.inventColorId == inventColorId;
```

Now suddendly this query changed it's execution plan and from milliseconds of execution it will take from 10 to 20 minutes for a single run.

I tried to reindex all the 3 tables involved in the query without success.

If I take a look at the query plan I see that an Index seek has become a Key Lookup, but nothing is changed in the query, in the indexes or in the tables!

Why is this happening?

This is the query plan when everything was working correctly:
[image: Query FAST]

And this is the plan now:
[image: Query SLOW]

What can it be?

Comment: Try pasting actual execution plans [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) so that we get some more information on your queries than just from the estimated plan.

Comment: Work around would be to use sp_create_plan_guide to force the desirable plan (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179880(v=sql.105).aspx). What is the version of SQL Server you are running?

Comment: @RigertaDemiri I'm sorry but the URL you provided is not working, because the query contains a StmtCursor that is not supported.

We noticed that your plan is using a cursor (StmtCursor). Unfortunately, Paste The Plan isn't displaying plans with cursors yet. You can flip the table now. (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: @DeanSavović I'm using sql server 2008

Comment: @Ludovico, great! Then you can use sp_create_plan_guide to force the plan you ant to be used.

Comment: @DeanSavović I'd prefer to understand why this is happening, the sp_create_plan_guide seems a temporary work around for me. Not so elegant..

Comment: Your query has parameters and the first plan cuold be built for certain parameter values that caused the optimizer to estimate small cardinality and to use nested loops only.Then for some reason the plan was evicted from the plan cache and the new one was built for other (sniffed)parameter values, the estimated cardinality induced hash join and now you have this plan instead of previous one. To see if this is the case find from your plans for what parameter values both of the plans were built

Comment: @sepupic Parameters are surely differents, this query is running on a loop and get executed every time with different params.
But if this is the case (parameter sniffing) how can I avoid that? I already tried dropping the plans for this query, but it hasn't helped.
I think that always the same (wrong) plan get computed.

Comment: Try to execute this query in Management Studio for one set of parameters  and for another; remember to add the recompile option at the end of your query when you use variables instead of parameters. This way you'll be able to see if there are different parameter values to cause the different plan choice

Comment: Have the statistics been updated lately?

Comment: @Jason Yes, tables and statistics have been updated 3 days ago (and also today, as I have done a dbcc dbreindex on the 3 tables)

Comment: In rough order of risk: `UPDATE STATISTICS ... WITH FULLSCAN`, `CREATE STATISTICS ...`, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR [UNKNOWN | @param = value...])`, `WITH (INDEX (..))`, `WITH (FORCESEEK)`, `OPTION (KEEPFIXED PLAN)`. Most of these, of course, assume you can actually edit the query text -- if you can't, a plan guide is your only recourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, probably the optimizer is estimating small cardinality and using nested loops only.

Since I can't edit the query text adding recompile, with index or whatsoever (the query is created directly from the ERP) the unique ways to solve the problem are:

plan_guide
refactoring the query

I decided to opt for the latter. I have splitted the query removing the join, and now it is working fine. (even if this is not an optimal solution. I don't like how MS SQL is working here)

Comment: If restarting/updating SQL Server is an option, there's also [trace flag 4199](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974006/sql-server-query-optimizer-hotfix-trace-flag-4199-servicing-model) to consider. From SQL Server 2017 onwards, the engine has a [built in feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning) to prevent this sort of plan regression.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for the tip, it useful to know about automatic tuning and SQL plan choice regressions. I will keep that in mind if we will ever switch to mssql 2017